# Is there a limit of elements that could be stored in a List?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, ilist

Is there a limit of elements that could be stored in a List ? or you can just keeping adding elements untill you are out of memory ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The current implementation of `List<T>` uses `Int32` *everywhere* - to construct its backing array, for its `Count` property, as an indexer and for all its internal operations - so there's a current *theoretical* maximum of `Int32.MaxValue` items (`2^31-1` or `2147483647`).

But the .NET framework also has a maximum object size limit of 2GB, so you'll only get anywhere near the items limit with lists of single-byte items such as `List<byte>` or `List<bool>`.

In practice you'll probably run out of contiguous memory before you hit either of those limits.

Comment: *Theoretically* that means you can only randomly access items up to `Int32.MaxValue`, not how many elements can there be, *theoretically*, of course.

Comment: @Martinho: Well, the current implementation uses `Int32` *everywhere*, so it's not just random access that's restricted to 2^31 items. (Of course, the use of `Int32` internally is just an implementation detail, but properties like the indexer and `Count` are part of the public contract.)