# Maximum length of byte[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, unsafe

I'm trying to create an array of `byte`s whose length is `UInt32.MaxValue`. This array is essentially a small(ish) in-memory database:

```
byte[] countryCodes = new byte[UInt32.MaxValue];
```

On my machine, however, at run-time, I get a `System.OverflowException` with "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow".

What's the deal? Do I need to use an `unsafe` block and `malloc`? How would I do that in C#?

Comment: I had no idea there were so many countries!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The current implementation of `System.Array` uses `Int32` for all its internal counters etc, so the theoretical maximum number of elements is `Int32.MaxValue`.

There's also a 2GB max-size-per-object limit imposed by the Microsoft CLR.

A good discussion and workaround here...

- [BigArray<T>, getting around the 2GB array size limit](https://web.archive.org/web/20180921190907/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshwil/2005/08/10/bigarrayt-getting-around-the-2gb-array-size-limit/)

And a few related, not-quite-duplicate, questions and answers here...

- [Is there a limit of elements that could be stored in a List ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730821/is-there-a-limit-of-elements-that-could-be-stored-in-a-list/1730836#1730836)
- [Very large collection in .Net causes out-of-memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657181/very-large-collection-in-net-causes-out-of-memory-exception/3657189#3657189)
- [what is the max limit of data into list in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906891/what-is-the-max-limit-of-data-into-liststring-in-c/3906931#3906931)

Answer (score 14):

On .NET 4.5 The maximum instantiatable length of a byte array is:  2147483591, or 56 less than int.MaxValue.  Found via:

```
for (int i = int.MaxValue; i > 0; i--)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[i];
        Console.Out.WriteLine("MaxValue: " + i);
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    catch (Exception ignored)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maximum length of a byte array is: 2130702268.
for example:

```
var countryCodes = new byte[2130702268];
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't do this in the first place. Why would you want to set all that memory aside for this in-memory database? Wouldn't you rather want either a data structure which size increments as you go along (e.g. `List<int>`)? Or (if preferred) use an in-memory database like [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)?